# How to get permanent access token for requests Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

For requests to API I use the following code:

```
$.get(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/baba/feed?limit=10&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAJVMIdHeh4JVZAyrvdJTC34qiJQ6PAC1VkRTLQXGDhAlpL1NALORrZAEJ2HksZB7OFu8RhhrbSs8whfpkQa8elTnmZBADzZAx7ew834knv7mMItvVGEN7gxp37mBVApQ03ePtF0MQJGFjAUUOeR8qNmVN8imDYsy9cGjRnHlFZAkmYh7bNlocZD&fields=message,from{id,name,picture,link}",     // url,
    function(data) {});
```

But this access token is expired every time. How to get permanent access token for requests Facebook in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Just use an App Token if it is the feed of a Page, it is valid forever. Do not use any static Token on the client though, Tokens are meant to be kept secret.

For user walls, you can only use an Extended User Token that is valid for 60 days. See the docs about how to generate one.

Another resource: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Okay, how to get or refresh token after date expiried in my sample?